# Jquery UI draggable positioning problem inside Reveal.js slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, reveal.js

My **jquery draggable** is working fine in a plane html page (where **reveal.js** is not present).

In my **reveal js** presentation I use **embed=true** [means I didn't use the full page for each slide. I used only a part of the full page for each slide].

Inside any **Reveal js** slide the draggable item is not moving with the cursor. It's only accurate when the cursor and draggable item is in it's beginning position. But when I pick draggable item and move cursor, the draggable item moves far from cursor.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the bug after three days of panic. The jQuery draggable is fetching problem inside auto scaled elements. And the Reveal.js slides are auto scaled by default. I just put the bellow code inside Reveal.initialize. This solved my problem.

```
minScale: 1,
maxScale: 1,
```

By the way, after solving the draggable issue, now all my slides contents changed their sizes and positions. Now I need to fix them.

Happy coding :)